By keyboard layout is changing sometime between boot and me opening a terminal window. How do I stop it?
I have us layout keyboard. I am using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and the i3 window manager.
In settings, it's set to US:

But when I reboot, it's suddenly back to GB.
.bash_profile also has "setxkbmap us"
My i3 config also has:
exec --no-startup-id sh -c 'setxkbmap us > ~/setxkbmap.log 2>&1'

and yet it's stubbornly set to GB until I manually change it with setxkbmap.
as a debugging step I added
exec --NO-startup-id sh -c 'setxkbmap -query > ~/setxkbmap2.log 2>&1'

and that log file gives:
joe@joe-main:~$ more ~/setxkbmap2.log 
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
joe@joe-main:~$ 

So clearly something is setting it to GB before I log in.
What's happening and how can I stop it?
as a debugging se

Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware, change keyboard layouts,  etc.) with the terminal command sudo journalctl  -b 0.
